# Specify resource-path in YAML header

Tags: pandoc

According to the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options), we may use `--resource-path=...` to specify the path to the resource directory.  E.g.:

```
---
title: Sample document
author: myself
date: now
#resource-path:
#- figures/
...

# Hi all!

Here is my sample document!  And also, there is an wonderful image in
this document.

![The wonderful image.](wimage.pdf)

Done.
```

The file `wimage.pdf` is located in `figures/`.  Compiled with the following command, everything is OK, file is found and embedded in the output PDF file.

```
$ pandoc --resource-path=figures test.md -o test.pdf
```

Still according to the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#default-files), I may also use `resource-path:` in the YAML header.  So I uncomment the corresponding 2 lines in the example above, and try compiling with

```
$ pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource wimage.pdf: replacing image with description
```

As indicated by the warning, the image is not embedded in the output PDF file.

Should the `resource-path:` in the YAML header work at all or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding about default files. Those are separate files that contain options and are passed via the `--defaults`/`-D` command line option. Putting `resource-path` in the document's metadata will not work.